# CapacitorJS Plain Javascript - Get video element from Camera Plugin

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I am in trouble with Camera Native Plugin from CapacitorJS on Plain Javascript, because I cannot get video element from Camera Plugin, I have tried to addListener to Camera Plugin with below code :

```
Capacitor.Plugins.Camera.addListener("loadedmetadata", e => {
    console.log("Work", e);
    return Promise.resolve(e.currentTarget);
});
```

But nothing happen when Camera Popup is showing, just log in console that Video loadedmetadata event was fired from **p-umxsnyaf.entry.js:19** like below :

```
Video metadata Event {isTrusted: true, type: "loadedmetadata", target: video, currentTarget: video, eventPhase: 2, …}
```

Any help and suggestions will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Which plugin are you using? https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v3/apis/camera ?

Comment: No, I am using the stable v2, https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/camera